# Strings.join removed in M3 - what is new syntax?

Tags: dart

The code below no longer works in Dart M3, and I couldn't find what the new syntax is.

Could someone please advise?

```dart
#import('dart:uri');

String encodeMap(Map data) {
  return Strings.join(data.getKeys().map((k) {
    return "${encodeUriComponent(k)}=${encodeUriComponent(data[k])}";
  }), "&");
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply use [`.join(separator)`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/Iterable.html#join) on `Iterable`.

In your case :

```dart
import 'dart:uri';

String encodeMap(Map data) {
  return data.keys.map((k) {
    return "${encodeUriComponent(k)}=${encodeUriComponent(data[k])}";
  }).join("&");
}
```

From [Breaking Change: Strings class is going away](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/topic/misc/W6ROk6I4yT0/discussion) :

> The Strings class (note the trailing "s") in core is going away.
>   If you used Strings.join(stringIterable, separator) replace it with stringIterable.join(separator).
>   If you used Strings.concatAll(stringIterable) replace it with stringIterable.join().

Comment: I had to use the following (Dart r18915) - "data.keys.map(" rather than "getKeys()"

Comment: Yes, sorry, I only modified your `.join` call. Answer fixed.